# Sails.js WebScoket how to create new channel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, sails.js, sails-hook

How to create new channel for emit in SAILS.js?

simple

```
io.sockets.in('ee').emit('messageName', {thisIs: 'theMessage'});
```

and then in Angular.js

```
io.socket.on("ee", function(data){
  console.log(data);
})
```

don`t work..

Comment: This begs the obvious question.. are you setting your event handler "io.socket.on" before you're broadcasting the message?

Comment: No... how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, I think it does the work you want but not in the way you mentioned:

1. In client side before calling the route which we use in server side add these codes:

   ```
   // Use `io.socket.on()` to listen for the 'hello' event:
   io.socket.on('hello', function (data) {
      console.log('Socket `' + data.id + '` joined the party!');
   });
   ```
2. In your desired route controller add these codes:

   ```
   // Have the socket which made the request join the "funSockets" room.
   sails.sockets.join(req, 'funSockets');

   // Broadcast a notification to all the sockets who have joined
   // the "funSockets" room, excluding our newly added socket:
   sails.sockets.broadcast('funSockets', 'hello', { howdy: 'hi there!'}, req);
   ```

   **Note that this "hi there!" message will not be received by the client which just joined. If you want to send a message to all the clients as well as the new joined one, just remove req parameter from broadcast arguments.**

For further information please check this link:
http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/realtime